# relative positioning of div

Tags: html, css, css-position

Basically, I have a form, outside of that form in this random space on my page I want to position a div (containing two buttons). I've looked at using absolute positioning. However, it is positioning it outside of the page wrapper.

How can I get the positioning to be specified from the corner point of the actual page and not the window?

Comment: could you share some code or an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get the positioning to be
>   specified from the corner point of the
>   actual page and not the window?

You need to add `position: relative` to the element you would like the `top` and `left` values to be offset from.

That might be your `form`, or it might be your `#container`/`#wrapper` element.

See here for details and a visual: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have your answer by now. But ill post this anyways.

A simple and short example which shows how relative positioning to parent is done.

http://jsfiddle.net/EadXw/

Answer (score 0):

If you want it positioned `top:0;left:0` on the page, place it immediately after the `<body>` tag.

If it is wrapped in anything the containers may change it's position.  Make sure it is independant and not influenced by any containers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should read up a bit on the flow of the DOM.

[Positioning with CSS and HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-positioning-19970819)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `<form>` element wraps your whole "page" and that the `<div>` with the buttons is the first child of `<form>`.

When you do this you can add the rule `position:relative` to the form and `position:absolute` to the `<div>` and move it around with `top` and `left`.

Another option is to have no position rule on the form and have `position:relative` on the `<div>`. This is more compatible with iPad and iPhone devices, which don't like absolute positioning. When you go for this approach be sure to have a fixed `height` for the `<div>` and a negative `margin-bottom` of the same size.